# Tensorflow model.predict gives instant results in android emulator but stucks on Iphone/Ipad after deployed to Expo App

Tags: react-native, tensorflow, expo, tensorflow-lite, tensorflow.js

I'm totally new to Tensorflow and new to React Native. I've trained a custom model in Teachable Machine and successfully made right predictions after loading the model in my React Native app.

```
let model = await tf.loadLayersModel(bundleResourceIO());
model.predict();
```

This predictions are really fast and accurate on Android Emulator. But after deployment of app the prediction part stucks without error and gives no result **(on Iphone/Ipad)**.

I've tried to use tflite instead but had no success to load the `.tflite` file localy.

Tensorflow backend uses `rn-webgl`

What could be this huge difference of performance between environments ?